# Calling UIKit methods from other threads

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uikit, ios-multithreading

I have a function that must be called from a non-main thread. In that thread, I am trying to determine status bar orientation like this:

```
   let currentInterfaceOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
```

But I obviously get a run time warning like this.

```
    UIApplication.statusBarOrientation() must be used from main thread only
```

My question is how to determine status bar orientation on secondary thread if you need it? Using DispatchQueue.main.sync is the right way but is risky for the reasons of potential deadlocks.

```
   var currentInterfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft

   DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                currentInterfaceOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
            }
```

What are the safe ways here using Swift?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a function that must be called from a non-main thread.

Add the orientation as an argument to this function.

Comment: Problem is there is a chain of functions and this one sits at the top of the stack, all these functions are called on secondary thread.

Comment: Could you give a small code example? I can't imagine that it is not possible to inject a dependency. To access `UIApplication.shared` directly is a little code smell. The easiest solution would be to create another global Object, where you set the orientation from `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation`